# How to return data from scrapy spider?

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

I'm a bit stuck on how exactly I can return the output of a scrapy spider so that I may use it in another function or in the global scope. In the code below, I have tried returning the res variable as you normally would for a function but it seems that it doesn't work like that for Scrapy and it's returning the following error instead for each of the urls in my list:  *return request, item, or None, got 'str'*

Thanks for taking the time to look into this!

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import logging

#disable logging for scrapy - by default verbose as hell
logging.getLogger('scrapy').propagate = False

#create the spider
class feedSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    #the spider needs a name
    name="scraper"

    # define the sources we're about to crawl
    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [feed for feed in feeds]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    # parse the response
    def parse(self, response):

        # Select the first headline from each RSS feed
        res = response.xpath('//item/title/text()').get()
        return res

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})


process.crawl(feedSpider)
 # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
process.start()
```

Comment: Can you just return response.xpath('//item/title/text()') and call .get() outside of this func?

Comment: Just did and the error is still there Spider must return request, item, or None, got 'Selector

Comment: Had you found any solution for this yet ?

Answer (score 0):

> following error instead for each of the urls in my list: return request, item, or None, got 'str'

Well, that's something, isn't it :-)

What you really want here is an [item](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html). Trust me on this! Chose your preferred way to define the item. Let the crawler chug along, producing items. Don't let it waste time with anything else.

Put the post-processing of item data somewhere else. There are input and output processors in the [item loaders](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) and there's the really cool concept of [item pipelines](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html).

But again, what you want to start with is an item!

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Thanks, it's my first time using Scrapy so I'm a bit lost as to how it all works! Can you provide an example on how I might be able to define and use an item in this instance?

Answer (score 0):

Simpler way to solve these issue will be returning dictionary instead of literal data

```py
data = { } 
data['title'] = response.xpath('//item/title/text()').get()
yield data
```

yield will be ideal choice if you want to return multiple things from pass function in non blocking way.
yield / return won't matter if you have only one thing to return.